# Issues while automating button click using AutoIT

Tags: automation, click, autoit

I'm trying to automate a button click using AutoIT. I can run the application using the following command.

```
Run("C:\HtmlToPdf.exe");
```

The tool **Au3Info** indicates that the title of my window is `Free HTML to PDF Converter` and that the name of the button is `btnConvert`. I try to click the button by using the following command.

```
ControlClick("Free HTML to PDF Converter", "", "[NAME:btnConvert]");
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: You should consider using `$button = ControlGetHandle(...)` first to check, whether you adress the control in the correct way. It's worth to check if `ControlFocus("Free HTML to PDF Converter", "", $button)` works with the returned handle. And as the **NAME**-Attribute is **.Net** specific, you should try to replace it.

Comment: After running a program, you have to wait for the window to appear before you can click any buttons on it.

Answer (score 2):

When automating a GUI with AutoIt there are a few things to keep in mind. The first is to use AutoItSetOption() in your script, and usually at the very beginning like so:

```
#NoTrayIcon
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)
```

I use option 2 for WinTitleMatchMode because, it tells AutoIt to match any substring in the title. Next you run your program and wait for the window.  I'll use an example from one of my scripts...

```
#NoTrayIcon
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

Run("Setup.exe", @scriptdir)
WinWait("Setup")
```

I got lucky with this program and didn't need to script too heavily, but I ran into a snag with the installer. The finish button didn't appear until it finished running some checks. So I had to trap the script at one point like this:

```
#NoTrayIcon
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

Run("Setup.exe", @scriptdir)
WinWait("Setup")
...click...
...click...
Do
    $Finish = ControlGetHandle("Setup", "Finish", 1)
    Sleep(100)
Until $Finish <> ""
ControlClick("Setup", "Finish", 1)

Exit
```

I also like to use the AutoIt Window Info Tool. I can drag its pointer on top of elements I'm trying to work with and get all the details about that control.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a UDF that does my bidding, passing in all the info I need to find the control or window. Example usage. 
CheckClickCtrl ('[CLASS:#32770]', 'ApplicationX - InstallShield Wizard', 
                             '[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]', , '&Next >' 5000, 0)

```
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Add_Constants=n
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#include <Timers.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include "log4a.au3"

#Region ;**** Logging ****
; Enable logging and don't write to stderr
_log4a_SetEnable()
; Write to stderr, set min level to warn, customize message format
_log4a_SetErrorStream()

_log4a_SetMinLevel($LOG4A_LEVEL_TRACE)
; If @compiled Then _log4a_SetMinLevel($LOG4A_LEVEL_WARN) ; Change the min level if the script is compiled
_log4a_SetFormat("${date} | ${host} | ${level} | ${message}")
#EndRegion ;**** Logging ****

Const $TD_BTN_NEXT = '&Next >'
Const $TD_BTN_INSTALL = '&Install'
Const $TD_BTN_CANCEL = 'Cancel'
Const $TD_BTN_FINISH = 'Finish'
Const $TD_BTN_UNINSTALL = '&Uninstall'
Const $TD_BTN_CLOSE = 'Close'
Const $TD_BTN_YES = '&Yes'

Const $formclass = "[CLASS:#32770]"
Const $Edit =   "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]"
Const $button1 = "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]"
Const $button2 = "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]"
Const $button3 = "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:3]"
Const $button4 = "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:4]"
Const $7zWindowInst = '7-Zip 15.14 (x64) Setup'
Const $7zWindowUnInst = '7-Zip 15.14 (x64) Uninstall'

unInst7z()
;~ inst7z()

Func inst7z()
    _log4a_Info('inst7z:Begin')
    CheckClickCtrl($formclass, $7zWindowInst, $button2, $TD_BTN_INSTALL, 0, 0)
    CheckClickCtrl($formclass, $7zWindowInst, $button2, $TD_BTN_CLOSE, 0, 0)
    _log4a_Info('inst7z():End')
EndFunc   ;==>inst7z

Func unInst7z()
    _log4a_Info('unInst7z:Begin')
    CheckClickCtrl($formclass, $7zWindowUnInst, $button1, $TD_BTN_UNINSTALL, 0, 0)
    CheckClickCtrl($formclass, $7zWindowUnInst, $button1, $TD_BTN_CLOSE, 0, 0)
    _log4a_Info('unInst7z():End')
EndFunc   ;==>unInst7z

Func CheckClickCtrl($formclass, $text, $ctrl, $ctrltxt, $timeout, $delayafter)
    _log4a_Info("CheckClickCtrl():Begin")
    _log4a_Info("Waiting for: " & $formclass & " " & $text & " " & $ctrl & " " & $ctrltxt)
    _log4a_Info("Timeout: " & $timeout)
    Local $time_run = _Timer_Init()
    While (1)
        If WinExists($formclass) Then
            Local $hCtrl = ControlGetHandle($text, '', $ctrl)
            If $hCtrl Then
                If ($timeout > 0) Then
                    _log4a_Trace(_Timer_Diff($time_run))
                    If (_Timer_Diff($time_run) > $timeout) Then
                        _log4a_Info("ExitLoop:Timeout - " & $ctrl)
                        ExitLoop
                    EndIf
                EndIf
                Local $hCtrlHandle = ControlGetText($text, '', $ctrl)
                _log4a_Info("Control Text : " & $hCtrlHandle)
                _log4a_Info("Control Text Search : " & $ctrltxt)
                If ($hCtrlHandle == $ctrltxt) Then
                    ; we got the handle, so the button is there
                    ; now do whatever you need to do
                    _log4a_Info($formclass)
                    _log4a_Info($ctrl)
                    ControlClick($formclass, "", $ctrl)
                    If ($delayafter > 0) Then
                        Sleep($delayafter)
                    EndIf
                    _log4a_Trace("ExitLoop:Normal - " & $ctrl)
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            EndIf
        EndIf
    WEnd
    _log4a_Info("CheckClickCtrl():End")
EndFunc   ;==>CheckClickCtrl
```

The results are as follows:

Install results:

```
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | inst7zinst7z:Begin
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():Begin
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Waiting for: [CLASS:#32770] 7-Zip 15.14 (x64) Setup [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2] &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Timeout: 0
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:#32770]
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Trace | ExitLoop:Normal - [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():End
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():Begin
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Waiting for: [CLASS:#32770] 7-Zip 15.14 (x64) Setup [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2] Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Timeout: 0
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Install
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:#32770]
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Trace | ExitLoop:Normal - [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():End
10\02\2017 14:32:30 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | inst7z():End
+>14:32:30 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0
+>14:32:30 AutoIt3Wrapper Finish


Uninstall results:
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | unInst7zinst7z:Begin
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():Begin
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Waiting for: [CLASS:#32770] 7-Zip 15.14 (x64) Uninstall [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1] &Uninstall
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Timeout: 0
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Uninstall
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : &Uninstall
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:#32770]
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Trace | ExitLoop:Normal - [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():End
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():Begin
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Waiting for: [CLASS:#32770] 7-Zip 15.14 (x64) Uninstall [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1] Close
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Timeout: 0
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Uninstall
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Uninstall
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Uninstall
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : &Uninstall
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text : Close
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | Control Text Search : Close
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:#32770]
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Trace | ExitLoop:Normal - [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | CheckClickCtrl():End
10\02\2017 14:35:00 | WIN-4VR4FSF2H8Q | Info | inst7z():End
+>14:35:00 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:0
+>14:35:00 AutoIt3Wrapper Finished.
>Exit code: 0    Time: 0.7732
```

Comment: You can see above, the calls to install and uninstall for 7zip, when it is searching for the control it wants. That logger is awesome.

Logger Author(s) .....: Michael Mims (zorphnog) the logging script can be obtained here: 

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/156196-log4a-a-logging-udf/